# I need to read the @salt_key@ and @Secret_key from properties file in Java. i.e declared in Java code

Tags: java

```
@Bean

@Scope("prototype")

protected SecretKeySpec secretkey() throws InvalidkeySpecException, 
NoSuchAlgorithamException {

String secretKey = "Fra@d@15gt";

String salt = "Sa@t5dS3@";

KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);

SecretKey tmp = secretKeyFactory().generateSecret(spec);

SecretKeySpec secretKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

return secretKey1;

}
```

Comment: I am not sure your question is very clear. Your title indicates you want to read values from Java code and a properties file, which would seem to be two different things.

Comment: In general I tend to close questions where there is no body text too - a good question _always_ has body text (i.e. not just code).

Comment: Actually, I need to read the secretKey & salt variable from the properties file in java instead of hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

First store secretKey and salt in configuration file like below:

```
secretKey=Fra@d@15gt
salt=Sa@t5dS3@
```

Then read it in java code as below:

```
@Bean

@Scope("prototype")

protected SecretKeySpec secretkey(@Value("${secretKey}") final String secretKey,
        @Value("${salt}") final String salt) 
        throws InvalidkeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithamException {
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);  
    SecretKey tmp = secretKeyFactory().generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    return secretKey1;
}
```

Make sure that string inside `@Value` should match exactly as what you have saved inside configuration file.
For different environments (like production/QA/local) there would be different secretKey and salt. For each environment, you can create separate files with environment-specific values.